# How to define application configurations in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've normally put settings like the below in config/application.rb

```
config.generators.stylesheets = false
config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
```

But in Rails 5 the message below is found in config/application.rb

> # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
>   # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
>   # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

What does this mean? Am I supposed to add an initializer-file for every config setting? And in that case, what should such a file contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should still be able to put the configuration in your `config/application.rb`, however the message is informing you that your environment specific configurations take precedence over those specified there, so if you have another configuration overriding any of such values in your `config/environments` those in the environment specific would be used.

If you're using the initializers approach, in your `config/initializers/stylesheet_generator.rb`, you'd have:

```
Rails.application.config.generators.stylesheets = false
```

and in your `config/initializers/time_zone.rb`, you'd have:

```
Rails.application.config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
```